# wordpress 3.1 custom tinymce buttons

Tags: php, wordpress, plugins

Setting up a blogger with wordpress. They're going to be living in the WYSIWYG part of TinyMCE (the editor).

Want to make them some custom buttons (to add in certain stock call to actions, for example). They click the button, it throws down the code...

All the plugins that did this are now broken in the latest version of wordpress.

Any ideas?

** THANKS FOR YOUR TIME **

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I actually just wrote a <strike>[tutorial for making your custom code](http://unrelatedmedia.ca/tutorial/wordpress-adding-custom-buttons-to-tinymce/)</strike><sup>Dead Link</sup>, and it's based off of [Jeff Terpstras tutorial](http://brettterpstra.com/adding-a-tinymce-button/) - just more refined and object oriented.

In it's base form it should do what you are asking with only modifying the output in the javascript.